# "put up" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

This is something in the context of making appointments, taken from the book titled "W is for Wasted" by Sue Grafton.

I've looked up the meaning in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20up) dictionary but it all looks slightly confusing, like several meanings might sort of be making sense.

> ... He says he’s in dire need of a nerve specialist and asked me to set up an appointment.
>
> I said, “Wow. He’s not due back until the end of the week. I’m surprised he’d **put up** with the delay.”

Would be great to know the exact meaning.

Comment: The phrase is "put up with.."  and it means to endure (a nuisance); to tolerate (a discomfort); to allow (an irritation).   There is also "won't put up with..." for the same range of sufferings.

Comment: @Hugh good point! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Tolerate** allow the existence, occurrence, or practice of (something that one does not necessarily like or agree with) without interference.

"a regime unwilling to tolerate dissent"

synonyms:allow, permit, condone, accept,swallow, countenance;

**Google definition**

Comment: "put up with..."   **Put up** is what you do to shelves.  Put up **with** is how you endure trouble.

Comment: Your example needs to use *put up with*, not *tolerate*.

Comment: @Hugh **Put up** is what you have to do when your in-laws come to stay.  **Put up with** too.